# Numpy: add a vector to matrix column wise

Tags: python, numpy

```
a
Out[57]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

b
Out[58]: 
 array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]])

In[63]: a[:,-1] + b
Out[63]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [ 9, 12]])
```

This is row wise addition. How do I add them column wise to get

```
In [65]: result
Out[65]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [11, 12]])
```

I don't want to transpose the whole array, add and then transpose back. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a newaxis to the end of `a[:,-1]`, so that it has shape `(2,1)`. Addition with `b` would then [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) along the column (the second axis) instead of the rows (which is the default).

```
In [47]: b + a[:,-1][:, np.newaxis]
Out[47]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [11, 12]])
```

---

`a[:,-1]` has shape `(2,)`. `b` has shape `(2,2)`. Broadcasting adds new axes *on the left* by default. So when NumPy computes `a[:,-1] + b` its broadcasting mechanism causes `a[:,-1]`'s shape to be changed to `(1,2)` and  broadcasted to `(2,2)`, with the values along its axis of length 1  (i.e. along its rows) to be broadcasted.

In contrast, `a[:,-1][:, np.newaxis]` has shape `(2,1)`. So broadcasting changes its shape to `(2,2)` with the values along its axis of length 1 (i.e. along its columns) to be broadcasted.

Comment: Note DSM's (deleted) answer shows a faster way to generate the slice of shape `(2,1)`: `a[:,-1,np.newaxis]` instead of `a[:,-1][:, np.newaxis]`. Read the [rules of basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to see why this works. Very cool.