# How to add matrix and vector column-wise?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following:

```
>>> matrix = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],
...                       [4, 5, 6],
...                       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> vector = numpy.array([10, 20, 30])
>>> matrix + vector
array([[11, 22, 33],
       [14, 25, 36],
       [17, 28, 39]])
```

This adds the vector and the matrix *row-wise* (i.e. each row being added the vector).

How to perform the same *column-wise*? The result should be

```
>>> ???
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [24, 25, 26],
       [37, 38, 39]])
```

I'm aware that I can use

```
>>> (matrix.T + vector).T
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [24, 25, 26],
       [37, 38, 39]])
```

However I have many such additions and using this double transposition will make the code quite unreadable. Is there a way to configure ndarrays such that they will perform addition along the first axis (instead of the last)?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587802/numpy-add-a-vector-to-matrix-column-wise It is not much more readable though...

Comment: I'd stick to the `(matrix.T + vector).T` since it is a very natural way of doing. If you are also considering the matrix not just as a 2d-array but a list of lists, it is very natural to add the vector list to each list in the matrix list. Thus, the dimensions match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the vector a column:

```
matrix + vector[:, None]
```

Comment: You can also do this (arguably more clearly) with `vector.shape=(-1,1)`. The `-1` basically coding for "keep the size of the vector" or defining directly `vector = np.array([[10],[20],[30]])`

Comment: Once you get used to it, the `[:, None]` version is clear and easy to use.